# HttpPost: Send image to web server and receive request

Tags: android

I am new to android so please bear with me with the incorrect terms used. I am programming an application that helps to identify the location with an image.
have send captured image to a web server.
But don't receive the answer from server???

Listen and receive information from the web server regarding the location of the captured image and display to user.

hier is the code to make Request:

```
try {
                response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
                entityReceived = response.getEntity();
                try {
                    String result = EntityUtils.toString(entityReceived, "UTF-8");
                    System.out.println("Response: " + result);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check Status Code with following code.

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

And [Check Status Code Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html)

Comment: that return any value because it crashes always on HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

Comment: I can't get you.. please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your post, you are not posting valid things to url which url want. Check your post by using that url with your post in browser, what result comes up.